# JWT token - Man in middle attack

Tags: security, asp.net-core, jwt

I was going through the JWT auth. It looks pretty good. However I have a question that is the JWT authentication prone to Man in the Middle attack ? Can someone get this token while it is being sent. If so, then with the token and a fake request(obviously with a correct url) the data can be fetched ?

Is this even a valid scenario ?

Any views are appreciated

Comment: Yes, a JWT is a bearer token and the security of the scheme depends on it being kept private by the intended recipient. If anyone else gets access to the token, they can impersonate the token owner.

Comment: This can be avoided to a large extent by using HTTPS and enforcing CORS

Comment: @Thilo Thanks for the answer. If that is the case, isnt that, this wouldnt be a best solution for end to end security ?
Does IdentityServer solve this ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "end-to-end security" and "IdentityServer" in this context?

Comment: @Thilo By end to end I mean, that can this scenario be avoided, where even if one gets token, he wont get the data

Comment: @AyushGupta I am wondering that even if we add CORS, cant someone create a fake request ?

Comment: @PraneetNadkar if you enforce is properly, the request can only come from your website, so it makes it harder.

Answer (score 6):

JWT without https is prone to man in the middle attack, You should use it with https protocol to minimize the risk.

You can make it even more secure by adding IP address of client as a private claim to JWT token and validate that as well.

Comment: so is JWT with HTTPS free from MITM risk?

Comment: Is using only HTTPS sufficient ?

Comment: HTTPS is sufficient to a large extend but 100% security is not reachable, Only thing you can do is making hackers life harder and harder.