# How to prevent JWTToken gets exposed in the same network if the system is online?

Tags: security, networking, jwt

Added the JWT Token for the system to prevent to get expose from others, But when I checked the same Network in Wireshark the token gets exposed, Is there any way the JWT token doesn't get exposed to same network, Even though the same network is secure but we can't believe then there is no Man In Middle,

Is there any way to prevent the token to gets exposed in the same network.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JWT token - Man in middle attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49424639/jwt-token-man-in-middle-attack)

Comment: we can't do anything, HTTPS is impossible for me at this point

Comment: Then you will need to implement so other form of transport encryption if you do not trust your transport. Without transport encryption, JWTs are subject to MITM and also less-invasive sniffing attacks, as you've seen.